# System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect. When Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312");

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, encoding, .net-core

Code:

```
// dotnet core version
// install-package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages
EncodingProvider encodingProvider = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(encodingProvider);
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312");

// full dotnet framework version
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var s = Encoding.GetEncoding(936);
        Console.OutputEncoding = s;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("中文");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I try to set OutputEncoding on Console, an IOException is thrown with: The parameter is incorrect. This happens on my AWS EC2 instance (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter), but it is working fine on my local Windows 10 pro machine. I've tried both dotnet core and full dotnet framework.

Comment: Sounds like problems with fonts on ec2 instance. If you have an access to this machine try to enter from cmd console: `chcp 936` to check if it works.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov hi Dmytro, thanks for help. if i type chcp 936. the response is Invalid code page. So can I install code page (936) to the machine?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll help but try to add keyboard language you're interested in via Control Panel. Maybe it'll fix the code page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DmytroMukalov point out the right diretion. Here is how to enable GB2312/936 code page on aws ec2 windows instance

https://superuser.com/questions/692709/why-sometimes-the-codepage-is-invalid-in-console

> In Windows 7 you could only set 932 code page when your windows system wide non-unicode locale set to Japanese (you don't need to install additional language support until you want messages in Japanese ;) ). Unfortunately you need to reboot windows after setting locale. I guess it is the case with other code pages you mentioned. After reboot your default locale will be 932 and you will have Japanese directories separator too

How do I view and change the system locale settings to use my language of choice

- Click Start, then Control Panel
- Click Clock, Language and Region
- Windows 10, Windows 8: Click Region
- Click the Administrative tab
- Under the Language for non-Unicode programs section, click Change system locale and select the desired language.
- Restart the computer to apply the change.